# Return NA when all columns are NAs in dplyr

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I'm doing some data wrangling on my raw data to get it ready for analysis.

I'm creating a varivale HEART that equals 1 when any of the HEART1, HEART2, HEART3 equals 1; when HEART1, HEART2, HEART3 all equal 0 then HEART equals 0. When all columns are NA, return NA.

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
HEART1 <- c(1,0,NA,0,0,0,0,0,NA)
CARDIO <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA)
ANGINA <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,NA)
SLEEP <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)

df<- data.frame(ID, HEART1, CARDIO, ANGINA)
```

So the HEART column will be (1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,NA)

How do I do it with the mutate() function in dplyr? I've heard of the if_all() function but how do I only select HEART1, CARDIO, ANGINA and leave SLEEP out of it?

Comment: Not very elegant, but you could use `df %>% mutate(HEART = as.integer(HEART1 == 1 | HEART2 == 1 | HEART3 == 1))`. There are more possibilities but in this case a direct solution should be sufficient.

Comment: @MartinGal Will this return 0s too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will spit out some warnings about coercing the columns to `logical`, but those can be ignored.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(
    heart = as.integer(any(c_across(starts_with("heart"))))
  )
# # A tibble: 9 × 5
# # Rowwise: 
#      ID HEART1 HEART2 HEART3 heart
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
# 1     1      1      1      1     1
# 2     1      0      0      0     0
# 3     1     NA      0      1     1
# 4     2      0      0      0     0
# 5     2      0      0      0     0
# 6     2      0      0      0     0
# 7     3      0      0      0     0
# 8     3      0      1      1     1
# 9     3     NA     NA     NA    NA
```

Comment: Great idea! Although in my real data set the variables don't all start with "heart" lol. Please see my updated post

Comment: You can use the `tidyselect` helpers to select the columns in any way you'd like, whether that's a sequence of columns, `HEART1:ANGINA`, a more complicated reqgular expression, or simply typing them out `c_across(c(HEART1, CARDIO, ANGINA))`.

Answer (score 2):

this is one way how you could approach it:

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(
  aa = c(1,0,NA,0,0,0,0,0,NA),
  bb = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA),
  cc = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,NA),
  dd = 1,
  you_want = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,NA)
  )

dat %>% 
  mutate(
    you_get = case_when(
      if_any(c(aa, bb, cc)) == 1 ~ 1,
      if_all(c(aa, bb, cc)) == 0 ~ 0
      )
  )

## A tibble: 9 × 6
#     aa    bb    cc    dd you_want you_get
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1     1        1       1
# 2     0     0     0     1        0       0
# 3    NA     0     1     1        1       1
# 4     0     0     0     1        0       0
# 5     0     0     0     1        0       0
# 6     0     0     0     1        0       0
# 7     0     0     0     1        0       0
# 8     0     1     1     1        1       1
# 9    NA    NA    NA     1       NA      NA
```

Comment: Nice approach!  But why edit OP's input?

Comment: Great idea! Although in my real data set the variables don't all start with "heart" lol. Please see my updated post

Comment: Well, the principle is the same. I have adapted the answer so that not all variables you are interested in start with the same prefix (for later readers/other use cases: in the first answer `starts_with` was used inside `if_any` and `if_all`).

Comment: Thanks @Gregor Thomas. Initally I was particularly bothered by the use of `df` as an object name and while I was at it I thought I could make it easier to understand (but there are pros and cons to changing the OP's input)

Comment: I'd generally recommend against editing input data without good reason, and even then it's nice to call it out and explain in the comments. FWIW I think concern about using uncommon function names as data frame names is pretty overblown. Names of incredibly common functions and constants like `T`, `F`, or `c` I do dislike, but `df` is pretty ubiquitous for "data frame".